# How to set minimum size of an mxGraph vertex (so tooltips work on smallest ones)?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I've got an mxGraph that has very small vertices, in terms of their label, because it starts with 1, 2, 3. The default size of those less-than-10 vertices is too small for a tooltip rollover. How can I set the minimum size of vertices so I get some extra width on the smallest ones and tooltips will be fired on rollovers?

[image]

Comment: I don't want to replace the user class of the mxCell itself, since it is representing a specific Node class that I use in my pan-genomic graph applications. Node.toString() gives its ID.

Comment: And I have a zoom feature so one CAN zoom in and see the tooltip; but I'd really like the rollovers to work at the default size, which is a pretty nice size overall and tooltips work fine on nodes>9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options.

You can set the size of a mxCell with the "geometry", or you look at Style.

You can register as many custom styles as you need. Refer to this example : https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/stylesheet.html

for a vertex, pseudo code would look like this :

```
var defaultVertexStyle = this.getDefaultVertexStyle(); // "this" is mxStyleSheet
var myCustomStyle = defaultVertexStyle.clone();
myCustomStyle["width"] = 100px; 
this.putCellStyle("myStyle", myCustomStyle);
```

and then you can add "myStyle" to any cell you want. You can customize shape, color, everything.